# Blazor Page (WebAssembly/WASM): How can EditForm and EditContext are always be null in SetParametersAsync?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a blazor page with the below markup.  I am trying to add custom validation to it, which requires the EditContext.

My page (abbrievated) is as below:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized Context="Auth">
    @if (_part == null)
    {
        <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    else
    {
<EditForm Model="@_part" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
              ....
</EditForm>
```

I have in my "code":

```
    [CascadingParameter]
    private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter]
    private EditForm EditForm { get; set; }
```

And ...

```
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();

        Debugger.Break();


        if (this.EditContext != null)
        {
            this.FieldIdentifier = this.EditContext.Field("Sku");
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.EditForm != null)
            {
                this.EditContext = this.EditForm.EditContext;
            }
        }
    }
```

In OnParametersSet, EditContext and EditForm are always null.  Everything else seems to be fine.  How could they be null?

Comment: Try to make a small _complete_ example. You have an `<EditForm>` and an `EditForm` and they are not the same. Not at all clear what you are trying to do.  See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks.  I had a misunderstanding that you could get the EditContext in the page.  I moved the code into a component and then it worked.